# Adding a soap message to a Service Reference in c#

Tags: c#, xml, soap, proxy, client

I have added a Service Reference that points to WSDL of the service. I can consume the service by creating a proxy and there`s no issue with that. My problem is that I need to send a specific soap message , and there`s some parameters that need to be include into the header and the body of the soap message (credentials and IDs).
How I can manually edit or add this soap message? without touching the app.config file?, there's a way to add the same parameters inside the code? such as:
soap:Header
soap:Body

Comment: You don't manually edit the message. You set the correct parameters when you call it through the proxy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still having my problem. if you said that I have to set the correct parameters, how can I manually set a soap message into theses parameters?

Comment: That's just not how it works. See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reference. I read the article and that what exactly did when I created my client. the problem is that I need to pass some credentials to the service. So that`s why I been trying to see how I could add this into the soap header and body.